# How to create a radius search in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

My objective is to create a radius search tool using the Leaflet API. It will behave like *How many POIs within the radius from a given point?*

Any tutorial or any blog forum link will be helpful to me.

Comment: Please check following link https://bitbucket.org/zakis_/leaflet-search/src/67f10df04639/leaflet-search.js?at=default

Comment: sounds like server side stuff. GeoServer has DWITHIN( Expression , Expression , distance , units ). http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [bounding box](http://bl.ocks.org/calvinmetcalf/4967350) example, it uses Rtrees which are pretty efficient so you may have better luck filtering out the corners of the Rtree bounding box then doing a straight up radius search.